# Error : django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty. while deploying app to heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I'm a beginner trying to deploy my first Django project using Heroku, but now stuck with the empty SECRET_KEY problem when I run the git `push master heroku` command:
Checked with local machine but my app running in local machine without any problem.
I've checked Other solutions on this site none of them seems helping me.

Here is the **error**

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 224, in fetch_command
remote:            app_name = commands[subcommand]
remote:        KeyError: 'collectstatic'
remote:        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "manage.py", line 17, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 231, in fetch_command
remote:            settings.INSTALLED_APPS
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
remote:            self._setup(name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
remote:            self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
remote:            raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

`
changed secret key once using python secretes module same error occuring.
Tried to do by Decouple module to access env vars, i've got an error so switched back windows environ vars.

**settings.py**

```
    import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
key = os.environ.get('SECRETE_KEY')
SECRET_KEY = key

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
# DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG')
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # User apps
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'storages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRETE_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "ap-south-1"
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = "s3v4"

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'`
```

Here is the *local machine server* running status

```
 (venv) E:\MY projects\Django_Blog\blog>py manage.py runserver
 Watching for file changes with StatReloader
 Performing system checks...

 System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
 January 18, 2020 - 17:41:29
 Django version 3.0.1, using settings 'blog.settings'
 Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
 Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add the environment variable in the heroku server settings?

Comment: Also check if you have given the right spelling for the secret key. It is "SECRETE_KEY" in your settings file

Comment: Added just now and my problem solved. "SECRETE_KEY" is assigned variable in environ vars. Thank You

Comment: @NagArjun can you further explain what you needed to adjust to solve this problem? I am getting a build error like this on digital ocean.

Comment: @ThomasByers just added "SECRET_KEY" and other required variables to environment variables.